# gulp-buster never "completes"

Tags: node.js, gulp, gulp-buster

I'm using `nodejs` `gulp` to process and minimize my `less` files and for cache busting I'm using [`gulp-buster`](https://www.npmjs.org/package/gulp-buster), however, when I'm adding the `gulp-buster` pipe the task never finishes.

This is (a part of) my `Gulpfile.js`:

```
var lessTask = function(event) {
    var response = gulp.src('./application/assets/desktop/less/**/*.less')
        .pipe(less({ paths: ['./application/assets/desktop/less/'] }))
        .pipe(autoprefixer( 'last 2 version', 'safari 5', 'ie 8', 'ie 9', 'opera 12.1', 'ios 6', 'android 4' ))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./public/lesscss'))
        .pipe(minifycss())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./public/lesscss'))
        .pipe(watch(function(files){
            return files
                .pipe(buster('busters.json'))
                .pipe(gulp.dest('.'));
        }));

    return response;
}

gulp.task('less', lessTask);
```

When I run that task I get this response:

```
H:\Binary\nginx\foobar.se>gulp less
[gulp] Using file H:\Binary\nginx\foobar.se\Gulpfile.js
[gulp] Working directory changed to H:\Binary\nginx\foobar.se
[gulp] Running 'less'...
[gulp] app.css was added to watch
[gulp] 1 file was added from pipe
```

And when I run the task without `.pipe(watch(function(...` i get this:

```
H:\Binary\nginx\foobar.se>gulp less
[gulp] Using file H:\Binary\nginx\foobar.se\Gulpfile.js
[gulp] Working directory changed to H:\Binary\nginx\foobar.se
[gulp] Running 'less'...
[gulp] Finished 'less' in 51 ms
```

Why isn't it finished with `gulp-buster`? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using the `watch` function I just piped the `buster` function.

```
var lessTask = function(event) {

    var response = gulp.src('./application/assets/desktop/less/**/*.less')
        .pipe(less({ paths: ['./application/assets/desktop/less/'] }))
        .pipe(autoprefixer( 'last 2 version', 'safari 5', 'ie 8', 'ie 9', 'opera 12.1', 'ios 6', 'android 4' ))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./public/lesscss'))
        .pipe(minifycss())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./public/lesscss'))
        .pipe(buster('busters.json'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('.'));

    return response;
}
```